# How to use protractor to check if an element is present?

Tags: node.js, async-await, protractor

Here is my code, I am trying to verify that if `exit_without_save` is displayed on the screen, it interacts with `exit_without_save`, in this case click, but it only shows me the error that it cannot find the element. Am I doing it correctly?

```
var new_button = browser.element(by.xpath('xpath'));
var exit_without_save = browser.element(by.xpath('xpath'));

await new_button.click();

if(await exit_without_save.isDisplayed()) {
     await exit_without_save.click();
     browser.sleep(500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

isDisplayed() returns boolean value, you can use if it is true/false in if statement.

```
if(await (exit_without_save.isDisplayed())==true) {
     await exit_without_save.click();
     browser.sleep(500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should make sure the element is present in the DOM first. The `isDisplayed()` method assumes the element is already rendered in the page. You need to wait for its presence first. Try something like this:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var new_button = browser.element(by.xpath('xpath'));
var exit_without_save = browser.element(by.xpath('xpath'));

await new_button.click();

if (await exit_without_save.isPresent()) {
     await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(exit_without_save));
     return await exit_without_save.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this !

**ExpectedConditions** API is used In protractor to check element is present or not.
**ExpectedConditions.presenceOf:**
An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be present on the dom.
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($('#abc')), 5000);
```

**ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf:**
An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. 
Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be visible on the dom.
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('#abc')), 5000);
```

**Solution:**
Use visibilityOf over presenceOf [More Advantage]

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var new_button = browser.element(by.xpath('xpath'));
var exit_without_save = browser.element(by.xpath('xpath'));

await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(new_button));
await new_button.click();

await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(exit_without_save));
await exit_without_save.click();
browser.sleep(500);
```